# Check all checkboxes not working IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have wrote a function to check all checkboxes within a particular fieldset, it works fine except on IE8. I really need it to work on IE8, does anyone have any suggestions as to why it doesn't work and how I can make it work? Maybe using jQuery?

Thanks

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML for the `checkbox`es and `<fieldset>`?

Comment: we don't have IE8 so please tell us if there are error message or no and if there error message copy it

Comment: i will recommend that you use `$("#parent :checkbox").prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? The 2.x branch does not support IE8.

Comment: A brief demo would be more helpful.